# What is MultiLayer Inheritence in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oop, inheritance

Is it like *a class can inherit from both an Interface and a base class*?

Comment: I don't know that term. Where did you find it? Did you mean "multilevel inheritance"?

Comment: There's also [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)

Comment: Actually, It was a interview question and didn't find the answer on google. @knittl

Comment: You don't inherit from an interface. You implement it.

Comment: There a couple of things you would benefit knowing about inheritance in .net. In .net multiple inheritance is not a thing, but you can achieve a similar effect by using interfaces. Other languages do have multiple inheritance. If you are asked in a .net interview about it you should answer that it is a thing, but not allowed in .net and to cherry on the top would be telling how it could be achieved implementing interfaces. The other big thing you should know is that interfaces are NOT inherited, they are implemented, it is just the sintax to implement them is identical to inheritance.

Comment: @KhaledShihab, Welcome to Stack overflow. Everyone has good points, and you could mark one as an answer, which will help others who encounter problems. There is multilevel inheritance in c#, and there is no inheritance from multiple classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you mean ***multilevel inheritance***, but it's just a chain of classes inheriting, starting from *some* base class.

It's like this example class structure:

```cs
public class Vehicle { ... } // base class
public class CombustionVehicle : Vehicle { ... } // intermediary class
public class Truck : CombustionVehicle { ... } // derived class
```

The `Truck` instance is still a `Vehicle`, so it still can use it's properties and methods (of course if the access modifier allows it).

Comment: Your first sentence lacks a word. Did you intend to say "There's no such term as multilevel inheritance"?

Comment: "_it's just multiple inheritance of classes_" That could be mistaken with [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) which .net does not allow but some languages like c++ and Perl do.

Comment: Yeah, something went wrong; i simplified that. Thanks, @PMF!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused here by the term **multi layer**.

**multiple** inheritance is not supported in C#. A class cannot directly inherit from more than one base class.

C# supports **multilevel** inheritance, which means that a class can inherit from a class that itself inherits from another class. For example: